# List comprehension causes "name ... is not defined" error

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of integers, called `x`:

```
x = [3, 4, 5]
```

I now want to make a new list of integers, called `y`, where there is a sequence of `x[0]` lots of `0's`, followed by `x[1]` lots of `1's`, followed by `x[2]` lots of `2's`, etc...

In this example, this would give:

```
y = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

My attempt was as follows:

```
y = [i for j in range(k) for (i,k) in enumerate(x)]
```

But this gives me the error:

```
name 'k' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I do this with list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to think of what you want expanded out into regular `for` loops:

```
r = []
for (i,k) in enumerate(x):
    for j in range(k):
        r.append(i)
```

So then the list comprehension becomes:

```
[i for (i,k) in enumerate(x) for j in range(k)]
```

and keeping the same order.

Answer (score 4):

You have got your ordering wrong

```
>>> x = [3,4,5]
>>> [i for (i,k) in enumerate(x) for j in range(k)]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Refer the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) specifically this line

> A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression
>   followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses.
>
> ```
> >>> [(x, y) for x in [1,2,3] for y in [3,1,4] if x != y] 
> [(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 4)]
> ```